# clearInterval not working in switch()

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #demo{
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="Snake(event)">
        <p id="demo" style="left: 10px;">--></p>
        <script>
            function Snake(event) {
                var x = event.which;

                switch (x) {
                    case 119: /*forward(w)*/
                        break;
                    case 115: /*back(s)*/
                        break;
                    case 97: document.getElementById("demo").style.left = "10px";
                        clearInterval(int);
                        break;
                    case 100: var y = document.getElementById("demo").style.left; y = y.replace("px", ""); y = parseInt(y);
                        var int = setInterval(function () {
                            y += 10;
                            var z = y.toString();
                            document.getElementById("demo").style.left = z + "px";
                        }, 1000);
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works pretty fine when i tap d(unicode=100) but whenever i press a(unicode=97) it goes back to 10px, then continues from where it left. (with the d). Probably there is a problem with clearInterval().

Comment: First you tap unicode=100 and then 97 right?

Comment: @maheshiv yes, first 100 and then 97

Answer (score 1):

Your `int` variable is scoped to the function. That means you're not dealing with the same `int` variable when the function is called the next time; you're dealing with a new one.

To use a single `int` variable, declare it in the scope where `Snake` is declared. **However**, that means instead of one global (`Snake`), you now have two (`Snake` and `int`). Globals are a Bad Thing™.

Instead, let's have *no* globals and hook up your handler using modern event handling:

```
<input id="the-inpue" type="text"">
<p id="demo" style="left: 10px;">--></p>
<script>
(function() { // A scoping function so we don't create globals
    var int = 0; // The variable
    function Snake(event) {
        var x = event.which;

        switch (x) {
            case 119: /*forward(w)*/
                break;
            case 115: /*back(s)*/
                break;
            case 97: document.getElementById("demo").style.left = "10px";
                clearInterval(int);
                break;
            case 100: var y = document.getElementById("demo").style.left; y = y.replace("px", ""); y = parseInt(y);
                var int = setInterval(function () {
                    y += 10;
                    var z = y.toString();
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.left = z + "px";
                }, 1000);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Hook up the handler
    document.getElementById("the-input").addEventListener("keypress", Snake, false);
</script>
```

**Note:** There may well be *other* things wrong with the code. But that's what's wrong with `int` and not clearing the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `int` variable has to be declared outside `Snake` function, in order for `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` to have access to it with every `keypress` event.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #demo{
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="Snake(event)">
        <p id="demo" style="left: 10px;">--></p>
        <script>
            var int;  // 1st change
            function Snake(event) {
                var x = event.which;

                switch (x) {
                    case 119: /*forward(w)*/
                        break;
                    case 115: /*back(s)*/
                        break;
                    case 97: document.getElementById("demo").style.left = "10px";
                        clearInterval(int);  // 2nd change
                        break;
                    case 100: var y = document.getElementById("demo").style.left; y = y.replace("px", ""); y = parseInt(y);
                        int = setInterval(function () {  // 3rd change
                            y += 10;
                            var z = y.toString();
                            document.getElementById("demo").style.left = z + "px";
                        }, 1000);
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and assign function and interval variable as properties

```
var sampleTimer = {
    int: null,
    Snake: function(event) {
            var x = event.which;

            switch (x) {
                case 119: /*forward(w)*/
                    break;
                case 115: /*back(s)*/
                    break;
                case 97: document.getElementById("demo").style.left = "10px";
                    clearInterval(this.int);
                    break;
                case 100: var y = document.getElementById("demo").style.left; y = y.replace("px", ""); y = parseInt(y);
                    this.int = setInterval(function () {
                        y += 10;
                        var z = y.toString();
                        document.getElementById("demo").style.left = z + "px";
                    }, 1000);
                    break;
            }
        }
 }
```

You can call sampleTimer.Snake(key which has 100 unicode); sampleTimer.Snake(key which has 97 unicode);

Variables are function scoped(that means variables are accessible inside the function). Once you call the function, variable life will end.

Or else you can do as suggested by @T.J. Crowder